# Как получить поля у класса extends Thread который уже отработал?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть класс который дочерний классу `Thread`. У него есть поле которое нужно для бизнес логики, как результат выполнения потока. И мне надо, это поле получить в основном потоке. Но я не всегда успеваю получить значение этого поля, так как `run()` заканчивает свою работу раньше, чем я успеваю его прочитать.

А мне надо успеть получить результаты каждого потока, и в том порядке, в котором они выполнились. Помогите пожалуйста кто чем может. У меня есть мысль может эти результаты записывать в очередь, но если она будет на полях `Consumer`, то будет та же проблема... Как это решить?

```
public class Consumer {
    private Storage storage;

    public Consumer() {
        this.storage = new UserStorage();
    }

    public boolean addAccount(BigDecimal amount, String name, Integer id) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadAdd thread = new ThreadAdd(amount, name, id);
        thread.start();
        boolean result = thread.added;
        // здесь печатает result = false
        System.out.println(result + " add");
        return result;
    }

    private class ThreadAdd extends Thread {
        private volatile boolean added;

        private BigDecimal amount;
        private String name;
        private Integer id;

        private ThreadAdd(BigDecimal amount, String name, Integer id) {
            this.amount = amount;
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.add();
            // здесь печатает result = true
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " run = "  + added);
        }

        private void add() {
            final Account account = new User(this.amount, this.name, this.id);
            this.added = Consumer.this.storage.addAccount(account);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> run() заканчивает свою работу раньше, чем я успеваю его прочитать.

Может я неправильно понимаю проблему, но по-моему Вы наоборот успеваете прочитать результат раньше чем поток начинает свою работу.

В любом случае нет гарантии, что результат будет в этой точке:

```
//запускаем поток
thread.start();
//сейчас неизвестно выполнился он или нет
boolean result = thread.added;
```

Примитивное решение: дождаться завершения потока

```
thread.start();
thread.join();
boolean result = thread.added;
```

Но в этом случае использование потока теряет смысл, лучше заменить на вызов метода.

Получать результаты выполнения из потоков исполнения удобнее с помощью пакета java.util.concurrent. Посмотрите классы [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) и [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)). Также нужно будет определиться с логикой (когда нужно выводить результаты, по какому событию) и написать код, который будет дожидаться завершения потоков и обрабатывать результаты.

Выглядеть это может так (код привожу для примера вызова методов, не тестировал):

```
// пул потоков, в данный момент исполняются максимум 10 потоков
private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

//Класс, который будет обрабатываться в отдельном потоке и возвращать результаты
private final AddTask implements Callable<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        //здесь логика расчета
        add();
        return added;
    }
}

//сохраняем ссылки на результаты
private final List<Future<Boolean>> results = new ArrayList<>();

public void addAccount(...) {
    //класс, который позволит получить результат
    Future<Boolean> result = threadPool.submit(new AddTask());
    results.add(result);
    //пока мы только запустили поток, результата еще нет.
}

//отдельный метод для вывода результатов, 
private void readResults() {
    for(Future<Boolean> result : results) {
        //ждем пока выполниться поток, получаем результат
        boolean added = result.get();         
        //обрабатываем
    }            
}
```

Если результат всегда true, то его можно и не возвращать. Тогда `Callable` можно заменить на `Runnable`

> У меня есть мысль может эти результаты записывать в очередь, но если она будет на полях Consumer, то будет та же проблема.

Подобную логику можно написать и на `Thread`, но в этом случае потокобезопасную обработку результатов и ожидание завершения потоков придется писать самому.

Comment: Но таким образом я должен точно знать сколько у меня потоков будет Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10) в данном случае 10 это ведь получается симофор? а если я не хочу симофор? Я могу получить инстанс ExecutorService без симафора? И что будет если придут больше 10 они встанут в очередь или выбросят эксепшн?

Comment: 10 указал для примера. Если не хотите ограничивать количество потоков, можете поставить число, большее чем максимальное число потоков. 10 — это максимальное число одновременно запущенных потоков, будет меньше — отработает нормально, будет больше — встанут в очередь.

Comment: Также посмотрите другие методы инициализации в [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). Либо создавайте пул сами через [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: а если я вызову result.get(); прямо в addAccount(...) у меня не получится однопоточное выполнение? то-же что с join? А то у меня как то подозрительно ровненько при логировании все потоки оди за другим идут.

Comment: @Павел получится то же самое, что с `join`. Метод [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) ждет завершения потока. Но проблема не в том, какой класс/метод использовать. Проблема в логике: Вы хотите получить результат в `addAccount`, но для этого очевидно нужно дождаться завершения потока, а при этом теряется смысл параллельного потока. Многопоточное исполнение должно быть асинхронным: в одном месте запускаются потоки, в другом — обрабатываются результаты.

Comment: Да я понимаю идея в том что разные аккаунты добавляются асинхронно в одну конкаренси мапу, но результат о том удалось ли добавиться я должен каждому вернуть персонально получилось у него добавиться в мапу или нет. А с методом readResults как мне понять если у кого то не получилось я же должен об этом сообщить типо не удалось добавить аккаунт

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56156/discussion-between-default-locale-and-).

Comment: Добавлю - эти классы довольно удобно использовать с лямбдами...